# Python Pandas: How do I average ONLY the data >1000 from several columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I just want to average the revenue from Revenue1 to Revenue3 that are > 1000. Thank you!

**Input:**

```
|Name | Revenue1| Revenue2|  Revenue3|
|Peter| 1000    | 2000    |  3000    |
|Jane | 9000    | 10000    |  5000    |
```

**Desired Output:**

```
| Name  | Average |
| Peter | 2500    |
| Jane  | 8000    |

Peter =average (2000+ 3000) = 2500
Jane =average (9000+ 10000 +5000) = 8000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try via `filter()`,`gt()` and `mean()`:

```
out=df.filter(like='Revenue')
df['Average']=out[out.gt(1000)].mean(axis=1)
```

output of `df`:

```
    Name    Revenue1    Revenue2    Revenue3    Average
0   Peter   1000        2000        3000        2500.0
1   Jane    9000        10000       5000        8000.0
```

**Breakdown of code:**

Firstly we select all the columns that Named like 'Revenue' via `filter()` method and it will give a DataFrame of columns named like that so we are storing it in out variable

```
out=df.filter(like='Revenue')
#output of above code:
  Revenue1  Revenue2    Revenue3
0   1000    2000        3000
1   9000    10000       5000
```

Then we will filter out rows where values is greater than 1000:

```
out.gt(1000)
#your condition
#output of above code:
   Revenue1     Revenue2    Revenue3
0   False       True        True
1   True        True        True
```

As you saw the condition gives you boolean values so now we will pass that boolean mask to out so where there is `True` in the above boolean values you will get the values and where there is `False` you will get `NaN` this is know as boolean masking:

```
out[out.gt(1000)]
#output of above code:
   Revenue1     Revenue2    Revenue3
0   NaN         2000        3000
1   9000.0      10000       5000
```

Finally we will calculate mean via `mean()` method on `axis=1` so the `NaN's` are ignored..In other words `mean()` method doesn't considered `NaN's` while calculating mean(because by default `skipna=None` in `mean()` method)

```
out[out.gt(1000)].mean(axis=1)
#output of above code:
0    2500.0
1    8000.0
dtype: float64
```

Finally we will assign this result back to df:

```
df['Average']=out[out.gt(1000)].mean(axis=1)
```

**Update:**

If `df` also has other numerical columns like 'Income' and you also want to include it in your calculation along with columns like 'Revenue' then use:

```
out=df.filter(regex='Revenue|Income')
df['Average']=out[out.gt(1000)].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice use of `df.filter`

Comment: @ThePyGuy Learned from you guys **:)**

Comment: Wanted to use `filter` as well, but saw you using it, had to use `select_dtypes` like in my answer, +1 for your answer, mine got DV lol, lack of UVs...

Comment: @U11-Forward If you wish then you can use Sir.....as `select_dtypes` will also selects columns other than revenue and also it will not work in case where any of the column contains NaN's

Answer (score 4):

or using a mask

```
df['average'] = df.mask(df.filter(like='Revenue')<=1000).mean(1)
```

```
   Name  Revenue1  Revenue2  Revenue3  Revenue4  average
0  Peter      1000      2000      3000      2500   2500.0
1   Jane      9000     10000      5000      8000   8000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try this out

```
 d['average']=d[d.filter(like='revenue')>1000].mean(1)
 d
```

Comment: I think this should be the most straightforward correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a condition of `> 1000`:

```
df['Mean'] = df.select_dtypes(int)[df.select_dtypes(int) > 1000].mean(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name    Revenue1    Revenue2    Revenue3    Mean
0   Peter   1000        2000        3000      2500.0
1   Jane    9000        10000       5000      8000.0
```

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the replies. I tried `df['Average']=df.loc[df.filter(like='Revenue').gt(1000)].mean(axis=1)`. I get error: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Comment: `df['Average']=df.where(df.filter(like='Revenue').gt(1000)).mean(axis=1)` or `df['average'] = df.mask(df.filter(like='Revenue')<=1000).mean(1)` ERROR: boolean array expected for the condition not float64

Comment: Finally, if df also has other numerical columns like 'Income', will the above code work still? Thank you v much!

Comment: @Peter updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @Anurag Dabas: this works: `out=df.filter(like='Revenue')` `df['Average']=out[out.gt(1000)].mean(axis=1)`. The use of .values didn't help in the alternative solutions, I still get errors.

Comment: @Anurag Dabas: Can I understand how the code works, pls? `out=df.filter(like='Revenue')` returns a dataframe with Revenue columns. But `out.gt(1000)` returns a table of True/False, so why passing this table into the column of out get the columns of Revenue>1000 for each row?

Comment: @Peter updated answer....added explainations......kindly have a look **:)**